# Edit a file before an rsync / mv

Tags: php, linux, bash, cron, rsync

I'm on Centos 6. I have a directory full of xml files that I want to perform an edit on and then rsync or move them to another directory on the same server.

How would I go about doing that and then set it up as a cronjob to run continuously?

ADDITIONAL INFO:

I guess my question is more of: how do I have cron run a php script and then when it's done (only when it's done) rsync or mv the file to another directory. I don't want the php script to be moved, just the files that the php script edited.

This is a sample of what I'd be editing. I want to add an absolute path to each media-reference source:

> `<media media-type="image">
>       <media-reference source="8084413.jpg" />
>        <media-caption>blah</media-caption>
>       </media>
>       <media media-type="image">
>        <media-reference source="8084411.jpg" />
>        <media-caption>blah</media-caption>
>       </media>
>       <media media-type="image">
>        <media-reference source="8084414.jpg" />
>        <media-caption>blah</media-caption>
>       </media>`

Comment: Please describe what you need to edit. That will help us show you how to automate it.

Comment: Well I would know how to edit it if I could use php. So could I create a php script to edit the file and have that be called by cron and when that's done it rsyncs or mv's the file over?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can stuff a lot into a cron entry, but it's tidier to encapsulate it in a script:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /relevant/directory
touch marker_file
php /path/to/script.php *.xml
find . -name \*.xml -newer marker_file -exec mv {} /destination \;
rm marker_file
```

Then in cron, to run hourly:

```
0 * * * * /path/to/above/script
```

Edit your cron file with one of below:

```
crontab -e
crontab -l > ~/crontab; edit ~/crontab; crontab ~/crontab
```

Comment: Ok this looks like what I might be after. What is `marker_file`?

Comment: Ah I think I might understand. The `marker_file` is there as a check to only mv things that have changed.

Why is `*.xml` at the end of the php line? Wouldn't I call the xml files from inside the php script?

Comment: Do what you want, this is just an illustration.